# Modifying username field in user subclass

Tags: django, model, field

How can I modify, in a model subclass, an attribute of a field in a parent class?

This means: I want to create a subclass of `djando.contrib.auth.models.AbstractUser` and have my custom model with the same fields BUT modifying the `username` field: I want to change its `validators` and `help_text`.

**Question**: How can I redefine a field in a subclass? The things I must change are not database-related, but model-logic-related, and my intention is to use that model in, at least, a ModelForm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the field by using the `get_field` method in the model's meta class:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    custom_field = models.BooleanField()
    ...

User._meta.get_field('username').validators = [list of validators,]
User._meta.get_field('username').help_text = "Help text"
```

Note that this will change the field's settings for all subclasses and superclasses of `User` as well, as long as they have the field, because the field's metadata is shared across all classes.

Comment: Thanks :D I forgot that part, now I remember :D.